# Underlying structure behind the infamous IMO 1988 Problem 6

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

This is the infamous [Problem 6 from the 1988 IMO](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=1988_IMO_Problems/Problem_6) which has recently been popularised by the YouTube channel [Numberphile](https://youtu.be/Y30VF3cSIYQ):

> Let $a$ and $b$ be positive integers such that $ab + 1$ divides $a^{2} + b^{2}$. Show that $\frac {a^{2} + b^{2}}{ab + 1}$ is the square of an integer.

The elementary proof is well known and based on infinite descent using [Vieta jumping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta_jumping).

What are non-elementary ways of solving it? Which mathematical structure is useful in creating the context for this problem? Is there an insight of the type where, once the problem is put into the right algebraic context, the solution is obvious?

What I have in mind is: notice, for example, how most of the steps in Euler's proof of the [Fermat's prime sum of squares theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares#Euler.27s_proof_by_infinite_descent) become trivial once re-interpreted in the ring $\mathbb Z [i] $, the infinite descent itself being replaced by Euclidean division. Is something similar applicable here?

Comment: Why do you call this problem infamous?!

Comment: @FedorPetrov If I recall correctly (hearsay, this was before my time) there was a minor outrage because the problem was just way harder than intended.

Comment: I thank the connectedness of Markov surface is relevant.

Comment: @DenisNardin it was solved by 12 participants, nothing special for problem 6 on IMO.

Comment: @FedorPetrov: Arthur Engel wrote: “Nobody of the six members of the Australian problem committee could solve it. Two of the members were husband and wife George and Esther Szekeres, both famous problem solvers and problem creators. Since it was a number theoretic problem it was sent to the four most renowned Australian number theorists. They were asked to work on it for six hours. None of them could solve it in this time. The problem committee submitted it to the jury of the XXIX IMO marked with a double asterisk, which meant a superhard problem, possibly too hard to pose. [cont’d]

Comment: After a long discussion, the jury finally had the courage to choose it as the last problem of the competition. Eleven students gave perfect solutions.” (quote via [Wikipedia’s article on Vieta jumping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta_jumping))  So it didn’t turn out unusually hard for participants, apparently, but the committee certainly thought it was!

Comment: I found this at quora: Among the eleven contestants who answered the problem correctly were Fields Medallist Ngo Bao Chau and Putnam Fellow Ravi Vakil. Among the many who scored 1 point out of 7 were Fields Medallist Terence Tao (who was, after all, only 13 years old) and Putnam Fellow Jordan Ellenberg, who had perfect scores in 1987 and  1989.

Comment: @Huxiyu Can you explain what a Markov surface means in this context and why it is relevant to this question?

Comment: @YemonChoi I cannot be sure, but the relevant diophantine equation with the name Markov is $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 3xyz.$ Travel within the tree of solution triples is accomplished by the same Vieta Jumping. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_number

Comment: @YemonChoi here is a recent preprint that shows the relationship of that material and lengths of closed geodesics; https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.05061.pdf  This other one does refer to the "Markoff Surface"  https://arxiv.org/pdf/1504.07099.pdf

Comment: Mordell discusses a lot of similar problems involving ratios of quadratic polynomials in two variables (solved by the Vieta jumping trick in the same way) in section 4 of chapter 30 of his book "Diophantine Equations" (pages 295 - 300)

Answer (score 18):

Indefinite binary quadratic forms, integer coefficients and discriminant not a square, possess an automorphism group; taking the Hessian matrix $H,$ an automorphism element is an integer matrix $P$ such that $P^T H P = H.$ The oriented part ($P$ has positive determinant) is infinite cyclic.
For the form $A x^2 + B xy + C y^2,$ with discriminant $\Delta= B^2 - 4 AC$ positive but not a square, Hessian
$$
H = 
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
2A & B \\
B & 2 C
\end{array}
\right), 
$$
all positive determinant $P$ are given by  integer solutions to $\tau^2 - \Delta \sigma^2 = 4,$ with
$$
P = 
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{\tau - B \sigma}{2} & - C \sigma \\
A \sigma & \frac{\tau + B \sigma}{2}
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

For the case of $x^2 + Bxy+y^2$ with $B^2 > 4,$ the automorphisms take on the familiar Vieta appearance, and the negative determinant ones can be taken to be interchanging the variables. With a fixed target $T,$ any expression $x^2 + B xy + y^2 = T$ can be transported, by automorphisms, to a region satisfying desired inequalities. These desired solutions can be thought of as representative points in a group orbit. Siegel's description of counting solutions comes down to counting the representative solutions, that is the number of orbits, as the number of literal representations of a fixed target number is infinite.

Probably worth pointing out that finding a generator for the (oriented part) of the automorphism group requires solving $\tau^2 - \Delta \sigma^2 = 4,$ where $\Delta > 0$ is not a square. This would be a bit much. However, for the special case $x^2 + B xy + y^2,$ the discriminant is $\Delta = B^2 - 4,$ so that $B^2 - \Delta 1^2 = 4.$ There is also the single-variable "jumping" argument, done extremely well in [Hurwitz 1907](http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/Hurwitz_A_1907.pdf)

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

**LEMMA 1**

Given integers $$  M \geq m > 0, $$ along with positive integers $x,y$ with
$$ x^2 - Mxy + y^2 = m.  $$
Then $m$ is a square.

**PROOF.**

First note that we cannot have integers $xy < 0$ with $ x^2 - Mxy + y^2 = m,  $ since then
 $ x^2 - Mxy + y^2 \geq 1 + M + 1 = M + 2 > m.$ If we have a solution with $x > 0$ and $xy \leq 0,$ it follows that $y=0.$

This is the Vieta jumping part, with some extra care about inequalities. We begin with 
$$ y > x  $$ and
$$ y < Mx.  $$ We have
$$ x^2 - Mxy + y^2 > 0,  $$
$$ x^2 > Mxy - y^2 = y(Mx - y) > x(Mx-y), $$
$$ x > Mx - y > 0. $$
That is, the jump
$$ (x,y) \mapsto (Mx - y,x) $$
takes us from one ordered solution to another ordered solution while strictly decreasing $x+y.$
Within a finite number of such jumps we violate the conditions we were preserving; we reach a solution $(x,y)$ with $y \geq Mx,$ that is
$x > 0$ but $Mx-y \leq 0.$ Since $(Mx - y,x) $ is another solution we know that $Mx-y = 0.$ Therefore $x^2 = m$ and $m$ is a square.

......

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

This one takes a little more work.

**LEMMA 2**

Given integers $$   m > 0, \; \; M \geq m+3, $$ there are no integers $x,y$ with
$$ x^2 - Mxy + y^2 = -m.  $$

The contrapositive of lemma 2 is that when there are solutions, $M \leq m+2.$ The bound is sharp, achieved at $x=y=1 \; .$ As a side note, if $M \leq 2,$ then $x^2 - M xy + y^2$ is positive or positive semi-definite. So, the contrapositive gives the other example at the wikipedia article, that if $xy$ divides $x^2 + y^2 + 1$ and $x,y >0,$ then actually $x^2 + y^2 + 1 = 3xy.$

Compare the contrapositive with Lemma 3 below...

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

This one took a whole bunch more work. I also needed some help from Gerry Myerson.

**LEMMA 3**

Given integers $$   m > 0, \; \; M > 0, $$ such that there are  integers $x,y$ with
$$ x^2 - Mxy + y^2 = -Mm,  $$ then
$$ M \leq (m+1)^2 + 1 \; . $$
The bound is sharp, achieved with $x=1, \; y=m+1 \; .$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your helpful post! I assume your answer means that the appropriate theory here is of quadratic forms (binary and possibly ternary due to references to Markoff surfaces); it will take me time to digest that. I am also curious if someone will post another answer.